# UIPickers data will not display from UITextField

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am new to Swift but I feel like I'm picking it up pretty well.

I have four UITextField with InputView's that display UIPickerViews, and I programatically placed them within the app. My code shows no errors, all UIPickerViews pop up (picker, picker2, picker3, picker4), but only the array from "climate" shows in all four views. So my obvious issue is... how in the world do I get the remaining arrays (environment, region, budget) to display in their respected UIPickerViews!

also, side request, how would I disable the text field so that no one could be able to paste anything into the text field

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var climateText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var environmentText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var regionText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var budgetText: UITextField!

var picker = UIPickerView()
var picker2 = UIPickerView()
var picker3 = UIPickerView()
var picker4 = UIPickerView()


//MARK: Arrays for PickerViews
var climates = ["Hot","Warm","Cold","Anywhere"]
var environment = ["Beach","City","Mountain","Rural","Anywhere"]
var region = ["Central America","Carribean","Europe","North America","South America","Anywhere"]
var budget = ["$0-500","$501-1000","$1001-1500","$1501-2500","$2501 and up"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    picker.tag = 0
    picker2.tag = 1
    picker3.tag = 2
    picker4.tag = 3

    picker.delegate = self
    picker2.delegate = self
    picker3.delegate = self
    picker4.delegate = self

    picker.dataSource = self
    picker2.dataSource = self
    picker3.dataSource = self
    picker4.dataSource = self

    climateText.inputView = picker
    environmentText.inputView = picker2
    regionText.inputView = picker3
    budgetText.inputView = picker4
}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if picker.tag == 0 {
        return climates.count
    } else if picker2.tag == 1 {
        return environment.count
    } else if picker3.tag == 2 {
        return region.count
    } else if picker4.tag == 3 {
        return budget.count
    }
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if picker.tag == 0 {
        return climates[row]
    } else if picker2.tag == 1 {
        return environment[row]
    } else if picker3.tag == 2 {
        return region[row]
    } else if picker4.tag == 3 {
        return budget[row]
    }
    return ""
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if picker.tag == 0 {
        climateText.text = climates[row]
    } else if picker2.tag == 1 {
        environmentText.text = environment[row]
    } else if picker3.tag == 2 {
        regionText.text = region[row]
    } else if picker4.tag == 3 {
        budgetText.text = budget[row]
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: maybe you just need to reloadcomponent after click on different textField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of using tags ([see point 2 here](http://benford.me/blog/12-dos-and-donts-for-ios-development/)), but to get you past this problem, change your `didSelectRow` function to do this instead:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        climateText.text = climates[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        environmentText.text = environment[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        regionText.text = region[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 3 {
        budgetText.text = budget[row]
    }
}
```

Your problem simply was that you weren't looking to see the tag from the picker view the user just made a section with.

Comment: I never thought to do this! But of course, as I go to change the code and test...Xcode begins to update! I'll keep you updated tonight if this solves my problem. Thanks, Michael!

Comment: Instead of tag's what would you prefer as a better option to display the Pickers from Textfields?

Comment: you can do "`if pickerView == picker2`" & "`if pickerView == picker3`" to determine which picker view the user just selected a value from.  Even better, *change the name* of the picker properties from undescriptive names like `picker3` to something like `budgetPicker`.

Comment: Michael, I finally got to try this new code for the app, but it did not work... Am I just missing something? I changed the "If" portion in didSelectRow to pickerView. I also changed the pickerView names to descriptive names. Te rest of the code remains the same.. stumped again!

Comment: I fixed it!! Your code did work! The issue was that, after my change, I didn't change the pickerView in my titleForRow. Thank you Michael, my night has been made.

Comment: And also, not trying to get carried away but its worth a shot..Since I have programmatically made UIPickers, do you have any advice on a done button